# Modelling short-term objects in Core Data app

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that talks to the server to get some items (`Item` class) for current user and store it. So far so good.

I want to implement search, that essentially returns me a set of Item objects, but obviously I do not want to persist every search result there ever be. Another use case is that server API has different endpoints like recommendations/ new/ upcoming/ that return the same Item object, but in different context, so I would like to differentiate between them somehow.

My first thought was to use a throw-away managed context, load objects from API in there, do fetch and when user is done just destroy the context. Is it a good idea in general? It saves code, because most of my VCs already talk to core data.

Comment: I have a good friend who is a real database guru, and he does exactly this. He uses Core Data for all his data storage and often throwaway contexts. I use it in my app to store images, and I always trash it on reboot as I don't want to worry about corruption (not that I've ever seen it) or migrations (and I do modify it from time to time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than throwing the whole wonderful infrastructure of Core Data away, you should leverage it to achieve your purpose.

- Add a timestamp attribute to your entity and use it to selectively display search results or even purge your store from old items.
- Add a category attribute to your entity and filter by category when searching.

Both can be achieved with an `NSPredicate` that you add to your `NSFetchRequest`. For example:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"timestamp > %@", [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:numberOfSeconds]];
```

or

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
  @"category = %@", @"new"];
```

Comment: Just to be sure, do you suggest that I should keep search results in persistent store, and use them, unless they're too old?

Comment: Right. You can decide when they expire.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Though my server has ranking algorithm for search results, I am not sure how can I translate that into my CD setup, and if I should at all.

Comment: Why would you have to? Let the server decide the ranking and CD just copy it so it can display the results as desired.

Comment: My worry is about preserving ranked order for items that can go under different search requests

Comment: No worries. You can always sort on the fly with predicates. Just keep all the necessary information.